# Como deixar o botão flutuando na parte inferior do elemento #container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Desejo criar um botão flutuante na parte de baixo de uma div. Gostaria que sempre que rolagem o scroll da div, a barra aparecesse no footer semelhante à imagem do chat que mandei do https://www.linkedin.com.

```css
#container {
  height: 450px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.msg-animation__indicator {
  animation: msg-indicator 334ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

.msg-s-message-list__new-message {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: blue;
border-radius: 7px;
padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">

  <div id="container">
    <h1 v-for="elem in items">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident a rem dolore molestias quaerat earum, autem accusantium repudiandae nisi suscipit modi voluptas, impedit delectus odit nostrum veritatis doloribus hic voluptates quisquam adipisci dignissimos
      aperiam iste. Quam vero corrupti, unde officia veritatis libero obcaecati maiores? Tenetur magnam a aliquid pariatur quam?
    </h1>

    <div class="msg-s-message-list__new-message msg-animation__indicator">
      Mensagem mais recente
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Semelhante ao chat do linkedIn.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se trocar `position: absolute` por **position: fixed** é pra funcionar não?!

Comment: Infelizmente, não funcionou. Pode dar uma ajuda @LeAndrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido usando o trecho de código abaixo:
Em que o pontos mais importantes são as propriedades offsetHeight,
offsetLeft e offsetWidth.

```js
$('#container').scroll(function(ev) {
  $('.msg-animation__indicator').css({
    top: ev.target.offsetHeight - 33,
    left: ev.target.offsetLeft,
    width: (ev.target.offsetWidth - 2) + 'px'
  }).show();
});

$('.btn-visualizar-mais-recente').click(function() {
  alert('Okay');
})
```

```js
$('#container').scroll(function(ev) {
  $('.msg-animation__indicator').css({
    top: ev.target.offsetHeight - 33,
    left: ev.target.offsetLeft,
    width: (ev.target.offsetWidth - 2) + 'px'
  }).show();
});

$('.btn-visualizar-mais-recente').click(function() {
  alert('Okay');
})
```

```css
#container {
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.msg-animation__indicator {
  animation: msg-indicator 334ms cubic-bezier(.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

.msg-s-message-list__new-message {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-visualizar-mais-recente {
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 210px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #0a66c2;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1rem;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 5px 5px 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p v-for="elem in items">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident a rem dolore molestias quaerat earum, autem accusantium repudiandae nisi suscipit modi voluptas, impedit delectus odit nostrum veritatis doloribus hic voluptates quisquam adipisci dignissimos
    aperiam iste. Quam vero corrupti, unde officia veritatis libero obcaecati maiores? Tenetur magnam a aliquid pariatur quam? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum quisquam, reiciendis temporibus similique itaque quia deserunt
    suscipit laudantium hic voluptate iusto repellendus doloribus excepturi quod earum sequi nobis vero quaerat! Quaerat modi, suscipit provident odio officia sint harum? Fugit minima, cupiditate voluptatibus facere eum alias nobis asperiores iure deleniti
    laborum quibusdam nam in excepturi, odio nisi magnam dolorum est accusantium placeat ratione et? Possimus sequi expedita repudiandae quia laboriosam. Harum, sequi maiores dolorem tempore voluptatum culpa eligendi reprehenderit vero voluptates error
    eveniet dignissimos, voluptate magnam tempora, est ad explicabo officia nostrum cupiditate doloribus facere quae iste minima ex. Doloribus, inventore?
  </p>

  <div class="msg-s-message-list__new-message msg-animation__indicator">
    <button class="btn-visualizar-mais-recente">Visualizar mais recente</button>
  </div>
</div>
```